# Удаление одного из элементов с одинаковыми id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такое:

```
<div id="block">
  <p id="p_1">text</p>
  <p id="p_2">text</p>
  <p id="p_3">text</p>
  <p id="p_3">text</p> // <---------
  ....
</div>
```

То есть могут попасться 2 p с одинаковыми id, как с jquery можно удалить 2й одинаковый элемент, а 1-й оставить? Если через id никак, есть как вариант с классами:

```
<div id="block">
  <p class="p_1">text</p>
  <p class="p_2">text</p>
  <p class="p_3">text</p>
  <p class="p_3">text</p>
  ....
</div>
```

Comment: Почему возникает такая проблема? Пожалуйста, опишите проблему более широко, хотя бы почему у вас могут появиться элементы с одинаковыми `id`?

Comment: @tutankhamun нужно удалить все повторяющиеся элементы, роли особой не играет, почему они повторяются )

Comment: Обновил ответ. Есть у меня подозрение, что у вас [проблема XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С классами так:

```
$('.p_3:not(:first)').remove();
```

C id например так:

```
var tmp = $('#p_3').removeAttr('id');
while ($('#p_3').length) {
    $('#p_3').remove();
}
tmp.attr('id', 'p_3');
```

**Дополнено**

Решение для поиска и удаления элементов с повторяющимися `id`:

```
$('[id]').each(function() {
    var idAttr = $(this).attr('id'),
        selector = '[id=' + idAttr + ']';
    if ($(selector).length > 1) {
        $(selector).not(':first').remove();  
    }
});
```

Comment: у вас на p_3 акцент, там любой повторяющийся может быть, хоть p_110

Comment: @Rufex Никакого акцента. Вставляйте любое значение и все будет работать. Вы хотите найти все повторы `id`? Это несколько иная постановка задачи.

Comment: да, нужно все повторы удалять